# What message queue libraries can be used on MonoTouch and Mono for Android?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, rabbitmq, messaging, mq

I'm looking for some pointers on libraries that can provide me with message queue end-point functionality for apps created in MonoTouch and Mono for Android.

I would guess RabbitMQ should work but I couldn't find any info on people using it. Have you heard of people using it in such setup?

Do you know of any other MQ libraries that support these platforms?

Comment: Did you get RabbitMq to work on Mono for Android?

Answer (score 1):

The RabbitMQ C# Client library works fine with Mono. I've used it for MonoMac applications, but not tried it on MonoDroid or MonoTouch.